# Querying distant relationships using a relationship table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 5.7 and mysql. I have a `services` table, and a `allowed_locations` table which holds which services are available in each city. 1 service can be available in 1 or more cities. Each city belongs to one state, and each state belongs to one country. I would like to return the service, city, state, and country but I'm not sure how to set up the relationship in each of the models. Can I retrieve the city, state, and country?

Cities

```
id
state_id
```

States

```
id
country_id
name
```

Countries

```
id
name
```

Services

```
id
name
```

Allowed_Locations

```
city_id (id from cities table)
service_id (id from Services table)
```

Countries
    id, name
    1, USA

States

```
id, country_id, name
3, 1, California
4, 1, Washington
5, 1, Oregon
```

Cities

```
id, state_id, name
1, 3, San Diego  
2, 4, Seattle
3, 5, Portland
```

Services

```
id, name 
1, Tax Services
2, Legal Services
```

Allowed Locations

```
city_id, service_id
1, 1
2, 1
3, 2
```

Services.php model

```
public function locations () {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\cities', 'services_by_location', 'service_id','city_id');
}
```

cities.php model

```
public $with = ['state'];

 public function state() {
    return $this->hasOne(states::class, 'id', 'state_id');
}
```

states.php model

```
public $with = ['country'];

public function country() {
    return $this->hasOne(Countries::class, 'id', 'country_id');
}
```

Countries.php model

```
//
```

AllowedLocations.php model

```
//
```

Controller

```
$data = Services::with(['locations'])->get();
return response()->json($data, 200);
```

Currently I'm returning a response like this

```
{
    {
        id: 1,
        name: Tax Services
        locations: 
        {
            {
                city_id: 1,
                city: San Diego,
                state: {
                    name: California
                }
                country: {
                    name: USA,
                }
            },
            {
                city_id: 2,
                city: Seattle,
                state: {
                    name: Washington
                }
                country: {
                    name: USA,
                }
            },
        }
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: Legal Services
        locations: 
        {
            {
                city_id: 3,
                city: Portland,
                state: {
                    name: Oregon
                }
                country: {
                    name: USA,
                }
            },
        }   
    }
}
```

Instead of a nested `state` and `country` I would like to return the city, state, and country name in the locations nested array. Is this possible?

```
{
    {
        id: 1,
        name: Tax Services
        locations: 
        {
            {
                city_id: 1,
                city: San Diego,
                state: California,
                country: USA
            },
            {
                city_id: 2,
                city: Seattle,
                state: Washington,
                country: USA
            },
        }
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: Legal Services
        locations: 
        {
            {
                city_id: 3,
                city: Portland,
                state: Oregon,
                country: USA
            },
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This was an interesting challenge, so I set this up on a test machine and worked it out.  Undoubtedly there are other ways to do this, but this works and will have the state and country available for use at the top level as you wanted.

The parameters won't show up in a`dd()` dump, though they will be available for direct access at the top level, and *will* show up if you dump via JSON.

I think the simplest way to help is to just set accessors on the City model.  Then, when the `locations()` method is called from the Services model, all the cities have the information you need.

**City model:**

```
protected $fillable=[
    'name',
    'state_id',
];

protected $appends = ['state_name', 'country_name'];

public function state() {
    return $this->hasOne(State::class, 'id', 'state_id');
}

public function getStateNameAttribute ()
{
    return $this->state->name;
}
public function getCountryNameAttribute ()
{
    return $this->state->country->name;
}
```

Note the `protected $appends = ['state_name', 'country_name'];`.  This allows those extra fields to be shown when you dump to JSON.  If you just need access to the extra fields (`state_name` and `country_name`), you don't need this line -- you can pull the fields from the City level part of the array now since we have the accessors in the City model.

The query needs to include a bit more eager loading now, so that those accessors don't try to get a name from a null value.  (You should add a null check into the accessor)  I suggest pulling it all in at once like this:

```
$data = \App\Service::with(['locations' => function($query){
    $query->with(['state' => function($query){
        $query->with('country');
    }]);
}])->get();
```

Doing a for-loop on `$data` will now give you everything you need at the city level.  E.g.:

```
foreach($data as $service){
   echo "Service id: ".$service->id.": ";
   echo $service->name."<br/>";

   echo $service->locations->first()->name.", ";
   echo $service->locations->first()->state_name." -- in the country: ";
   echo $service->locations->first()->country_name;

   echo "<br/><br/><br/>";
}
```

This successfully yields:

```
Service id: 1: Tax Services
Annapolis, Maryland -- in the country: USA

Service id: 2: Legal Services
Potomac, Maryland -- in the country: USA
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly your relationships should look something like this:

Service.php

```
public function cities()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(City::class);
}
```

City.php

```
public function services()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Service::class);
}

public function state()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(State::class);
}
```

If possible, I'd stick with the [default](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) and rename the pivot table to `city_service`

State.php

```
public function cities()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\City');
}

public function country()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Country');
}
```

Country.php

```
public function states()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\State');
}
```

In order to get the desired result you would have to make use of [accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators)

City.php

```
public function getState ()
{
    return $this->state->name;
}

public function getCountry ()
{
    $country = Country::findOrFail($this->state->country_id);
    return $country->name;
}
```

Now this is a bit costly but [hasManyThrough()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) wouldn't work here because you need the reverse relationship. This has been [proposed](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/10711) but not accepted. There's a [package](https://github.com/znck/belongs-to-through) but not sure if it's stable. Seems abandoned.

Anyway, you should be able to query this and get the desired result with:

```
$services = Service::with('cities')->get();
```

Comment: Mutators won't work here.  If he applies mutators, it won't show up at run time during his output - he is trying to get the relations a few levels higher upon output - nothing to do with saving.